# How to Remove Malicious Code from WordPresss Website?

Tags: wordpress, malware

I have created my website by myself. Recently, I found malicious code is appearing in my website as 
" script type="text/javascript" src="http://12js.org/jquery.js">

Sometimes, this code is appeared in source code. Another time, it is disappeared. It is like a re-infection.

I cannot find this code & I need to solve this issue. Anyone here to help me??

I am suffering with this problem.

Comment: Hi @Sohrab, I have installed Wordfence Security plugin and scanned it. I couldn't find any of issue, but that script is appearing at website source code. When I refreshed the browser, this malicious script is disappeared. And slo, sometimes, it is appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search your theme and plugin code files.

Look for the below code  [WP function malicious code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ0fK.png)